# EntitySetController $expand and $select not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I'm trying to get pages of results for a table, using `OData` provided by an `EntitySetController`. However all of my requests for `$select` and `$expand` fail. Any ideas?

I'm using Entity Framework v6 and System.Web.Http.OData v5.

My entity:

```
public partial class Contact : BaseEntity
{
    [Column("cont_id"), Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("cust_id"), EitherRequired("SupplierId", Exclusive = true)]
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

    [Column("supp_id")]
    public int? SupplierId { get; set; }

    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }

    [Column("cont_title"), Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true), StringLength(5)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Column("cont_firstname"), Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true), StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column("cont_lastname"), Display(Name = "Last Name"), Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true), StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Column("cont_phone"), DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber), StringLength(20)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public abstract class RepositoryController<TEntity, TKey> : EntitySetController<TEntity, TKey>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
    protected readonly IRepository<TEntity> repository;
    protected readonly Func<TEntity, TKey> keySelector;

    public RepositoryController(IRepository<TEntity> repository, Func<TEntity, TKey> keySelector)
        : base()
    {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.keySelector = keySelector;
    }

    // GET api/entity
    [HttpGet]
    [Queryable]
    public override IQueryable<TEntity> Get()
    {
        return repository.Get();
    }

    public override void Delete(TKey key)
    {
        repository.Delete(GetEntityByKey(key));
        UnitOfWork.Save();
    }

    protected override TEntity GetEntityByKey(TKey key)
    {
        return repository.Get(key);
    }

    protected override TKey GetKey(TEntity entity)
    {
        return keySelector(entity);
    }

    protected override TEntity CreateEntity(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState));
        }

        var result = repository.Insert(entity);
        UnitOfWork.Save();
        return result;
    }

    protected override TEntity UpdateEntity(TKey key, TEntity update)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState));
        }

        repository.Update(update, key);
        UnitOfWork.Save();
        return update;
    }
}
```

My request: `http://localhost:60642/odata/Contact?$inlinecount=allpages&$top=20&$expand=Customer,Supplier`

The result:

```
{
  "odata.error":{
    "code":"","message":{
      "lang":"en-US","value":"The query specified in the URI is not valid."
    },"innererror":{
      "message":"Could not find a property named 'Customer' on type 'System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectAllAndExpand_1OfContact'.","type":"Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException","stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SyntacticAst.ExpandBinder.GenerateExpandItem(ExpandTermToken tokenIn)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SyntacticAst.ExpandBinder.Bind(ExpandToken tokenIn)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SelectExpandSemanticBinder.Parse(IEdmEntityType elementType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet, ExpandToken expandToken, SelectToken selectToken, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ODataUriParser.ParseSelectAndExpandImplementation(String select, String expand, IEdmEntityType elementType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ODataUriParser.ParseSelectAndExpand(String select, String expand, IEdmEntityType elementType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.SelectExpandQueryOption.get_SelectExpandClause()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.SelectExpandQueryValidator.Validate(SelectExpandQueryOption selectExpandQueryOption, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.SelectExpandQueryOption.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequestMessage request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)"
    }
  }
}
```

But I see it on `$metadata`:

```
<EntityType Name="Contact">
    <Key>
        <PropertyRef Name="Id"/>
    </Key>
    <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false"/>
    <Property Name="CustomerId" Type="Edm.Int32"/>
    <Property Name="SupplierId" Type="Edm.Int32"/>
    <Property Name="Title" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
    <Property Name="FirstName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
    <Property Name="LastName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false"/>
    <Property Name="PhoneNumber" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <NavigationProperty Name="Customer" Relationship="Vantage.Data.Core.Entities.Vantage_Data_Core_Entities_Contact_Customer_Vantage_Data_Core_Entities_Customer_CustomerPartner" ToRole="Customer" FromRole="CustomerPartner"/>
    <NavigationProperty Name="Supplier" Relationship="Vantage.Data.Core.Entities.Vantage_Data_Core_Entities_Contact_Supplier_Vantage_Data_Core_Entities_Supplier_SupplierPartner" ToRole="Supplier" FromRole="SupplierPartner"/>
</EntityType>
```

I get a similar exception for selects. What' wrong?

Edit: Update. I get a different error if I try to filter something on the root entity while also expanding. Seems the entity truly is screwed.

`http://localhost:60642/odata/Contact?$top=20&$inlinecount=allpages&$filter=substringof('ORDERS',%20LastName)%20eq%20true&$expand=Customer,Supplier`

```
{
  "odata.error":{
    "code":"","message":{
      "lang":"en-US","value":"The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'LastName' on type 'System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectAllAndExpand_1OfContact'."
    },"innererror":{
      "message":"Could not find a property named 'LastName' on type 'System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectAllAndExpand_1OfContact'.","type":"Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataException","stacktrace":"   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.EndPathBinder.GeneratePropertyAccessQueryForOpenType(EndPathToken endPathToken, SingleValueNode parentNode)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.EndPathBinder.BindEndPath(EndPathToken endPathToken, BindingState state)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.BindEndPath(EndPathToken endPathToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.Bind(QueryToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.BindFunctionParameter(FunctionParameterToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.Bind(QueryToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.FunctionCallBinder.<BindFunctionCall>b__6(FunctionParameterToken ar)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.FunctionCallBinder.BindFunctionCall(FunctionCallToken functionCallToken, BindingState state)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.BindFunctionCall(FunctionCallToken functionCallToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.Bind(QueryToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.BinaryOperatorBinder.GetOperandFromToken(BinaryOperatorKind operatorKind, QueryToken queryToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.BinaryOperatorBinder.BindBinaryOperator(BinaryOperatorToken binaryOperatorToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.BindBinaryOperator(BinaryOperatorToken binaryOperatorToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.MetadataBinder.Bind(QueryToken token)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.FilterBinder.BindFilter(QueryToken filter)\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.ODataUriParser.ParseFilterImplementation(String filter, IEdmType elementType, IEdmEntitySet entitySet)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.get_FilterClause()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.FilterQueryValidator.Validate(FilterQueryOption filterQueryOption, ODataValidationSettings settings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Validators.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequestMessage request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object response, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Update: I've updated to the latest prerelease of System.Web.Http.OData and still have this issue.

Comment: I just tried this case with lighter entities but it worked without any flaw. Can you extract the Entities-Web API OData part out of your project and share it so that I can take a look?

Comment: I've tried to make a new project to demonstrate my error, but so far I haven't been able to recreate it with a stripped down project. I guess I will need to steadily add features until I find the one that causes this. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, then I think the issue is induced by some other piece of code that depends on your entities, or something on which your Web API also depends. Will wait for your update.

Comment: Can I have the full code what customer and Supplier class contains?

Comment: I've updated the question with my latest findings. Still broken if anyone can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your own attribute you need to register it!

Just call `config.EnableQuerySupport(new ControlledQueryableAttribute());`

Answer (score 3):

I came across a similar issue in OData V4. In this case it turned out if you used an attribute on the Get method and registered another attribute in your config, it errors because you are calling the EnableQuery code twice:

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<RegionEntity> Get()
{
    var result = _regionService.GetAll();
    return result;
}
```

and in the configuration

```
config.AddODataQueryFilter(new SecureAccessAttribute());
```

As the SecureAccessAttribute extended EnableQueryAttribute the first call of Validate worked fine, the second could not find the property, so although it doesn't seem to be documented, ensure not to call this twice for one query!

Comment: How did you make sure that it's not being called twice? I am facing the same issue even when only using it as an attribute instead of EnableQuery.

Comment: I just had to find out where the second location was and remove it. In my case it was because we were adding it in the configuration and as an attribute, in your case I believe for some reason the configuration is called twice or the attribute is called twice.

Comment: Thanks, I found that I had two calls to config.AddODataQueryFilter() in different places, one with a filter and one without. I removed the one without and my problems were gone.

Answer (score 1):

NavigationProperties are different to Properties, I suggest checking this first by creating a regular "Customer" property.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it. Was slowly deleting parts of my solution until it worked.

My shorthand queryable attribute broke it:

```
public sealed class ControlledQueryableAttribute : QueryableAttribute
{
    public ControlledQueryableAttribute()
    {
        this.AllowedArithmeticOperators = AllowedArithmeticOperators.None;
        this.AllowedFunctions = AllowedFunctions.AllFunctions;
        this.AllowedLogicalOperators = AllowedLogicalOperators.All;
        this.AllowedQueryOptions =
            AllowedQueryOptions.Skip |
            AllowedQueryOptions.Top |
            AllowedQueryOptions.Filter |
            AllowedQueryOptions.OrderBy |
            AllowedQueryOptions.InlineCount |
            AllowedQueryOptions.Select |
            AllowedQueryOptions.Expand;
        this.MaxTop = 100;
    }
}
```

Seems that simply having this super-class masked something that `$expand` or `$select` needed. I hadn't considered it yet as seemed like such a simple thing.

Confirmed on a simple test solution.

Comment: Ran into this same issue.  Seems to still be a lot of problems like this with the OData support.

Answer (score 0):

With OData V4, It will not work even if we specify [EnableQuery] for Controllers or Methods within the controllers. So remove any attribute if you have already enabled the querying globally.