# $select and $expand Odata V4 commands are generating an error

Tags: select, asp.net-web-api, odata, expand

I am using:

1. .NET Framework 4.7.2
2. Visual Studio 2017
3. OData V4
4. Web API V 5.2.4 with Entity Framework V6.2 code first with existing MS SQL DB

My `$expand` and `$select` commands are generating an error. For example, when I use the select command as follows:

```
http://localhost:62681/data/Advances?$select=Description
```

I get the following error:

> The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a
>   property named 'Description' on type
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Expressions.SelectSome_1OfAdvance'

`$filter` and `$orderby` do work

The odd thing is that this used to work a couple of weeks ago, but when I came back from vacation I could not get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

I've scoured the internet for any clue to my problem, but no luck.

I've upgraded to  Microsoft.OData.Core version=7.5.0 and Microsoft.OData.Edm" version="7.5.0

My register method in WebApi.Config does have the line `config.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Count().MaxTop(null);`

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();           

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(); 


        config.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().Count().MaxTop(null);

        builder.EntitySet<Advance>("Advances");
        builder.EntitySet<Advance_Payments>("Advance_Payments");

        config.MapODataServiceRoute(
            routeName: "ODataRoute",
            routePrefix: "data",
            model: builder.GetEdmModel());

        config.AddODataQueryFilter(new SecureAccess2Attribute());
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution in another stack overflow posting

[EntitySetController $expand and $select not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20423505/entitysetcontroller-expand-and-select-not-working)

Go down about 2/3 of the page and look for a posting that starts with:

I came across a similar issue in OData V4. In this case it turned out if you used an attribute on the Get method and registered another attribute in your config, it errors because you are calling the EnableQuery code twice:

Answer (score 0):

For OData V4, Remove the attribute [EnableQuery] on Controllers/Methods in the controller class IF you have enabled it globally. It accepts it only at one place.